# Twilio conversation connection error, the network connection was lost

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-conversations

Using Twilio conversations API in iOS Swift app. Obtaining token from our server, initialized `TwilioConversationsClient` with this token,

```swift
    func loginWithAccessToken(_ token: String) {
        // Set up Twilio Conversations client
        TwilioConversationsClient.conversationsClient(withToken: token,
                                                      properties: nil,
                                                      delegate: self) { (result, client) in
            self.client = client
        }
    }
```

Expecting the client to synchronize with Twilio. Instead I receive error messages.

```
2023-03-22 22:44:46.186396-0700 app[21875:865489] Connection not set before response is received, failing task
2023-03-22 22:44:46.194863-0700 app[21875:865489] Task <724658EF-E3D3-4554-83C5-0975EE6C738C>.<1> finished with error [-1005] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://tsock.us1.twilio.com:443/v3/wsconnect, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://tsock.us1.twilio.com:443/v3/wsconnect, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalWebSocketTask <724658EF-E3D3-4554-83C5-0975EE6C738C>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalWebSocketTask <724658EF-E3D3-4554-83C5-0975EE6C738C>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}
```

Ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Is there some additional step to enable the client or to enable to app to communicate with that URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the issue was caused by DBDebugTookit package from Cocoapods. Removing it from the app (we weren't using it), resolve the issue.